# Access default entity fields in backend module - custom TYPO3 ext

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

TYPO3 v7.6.13 / Extension Builder 7.6.18

We have created a custom TYPO3 extension that offers basic CRUD functionality. When we created the extension we enabled the "Hidden" and "start/endtime" fields in the entity object (via extension builder).

In our backend module, we want to the ability to show and edit the Hidden and start/endtime fields.

If I access any of my records via List > MyObjectFolder these fields are visible.

How do I call them in my backend module?

Thanks again.

Comment: A bit of a guess into the dark: The fields you mention should be in the TCA, under types or palettes. Furthermore they need to be mentioned in "interface" => "showRecordFieldList". If those rules apply, they should be shown in the backend... Maybe you could post your TCA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your extension uses Extbase MVC, you need to manipulate the Query the Repository uses to read objects, calling `setIgnoreEnableFields(true);` on the QuerySettings used by the Query. Usually you'd do this by overriding the `createQuery` method on your Repository, or you can do it by adding a custom method on the Repository which you for example call `findAllIncludingDisabled()`.

See also http://mbless.de/blog/2015/03/05/typo3-extbase-query-methods.html#query-settings

Comment: But that describes how to show them in the frontend CRUD. Isn't Tom asking about the backend, where TCA rules?

Comment: Yes - it's the backend I need them.

Comment: This also applies if you create a custom backend module in Extbase and use the Repository of your entity to create a list of objects. From what I understood, this is what is being attempted (going from the use of the word "entity" and the fact that this is not shown through the list module). The same restrictions are automatically applied in backend as in frontend when you use the Repository.